# copyright character in vim

Tags: vim, unicode, digraphs

I used to get this copyright symbol in vim earlier through some keys' combination.  Can someone help me with it now?  I simply fail to recollect it.

Also, if possible, share some more of such characters... someone might need it sometime.

Answer (score 26):

```
:digraphs
```

shows the list of digraphs you can use.  I see the copyright symbol as number 169, which has a key combo of "Co".  To recreate that in edit mode, hit Ctrl+k, then type "Co", and you should have a copyright symbol.

Answer (score 10):

Ctrl-K
Co

Should do it

Answer (score 1):

In insert mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> will insert copyright © symbol.

`:digraphs` will give key combinations for other special characters.